# Access attributes between linked agents in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

In a project I've created, for example, 1000 humans.
Now, if a probability is satisfied, then I create a dog and I link him to a human. Here we go:

```
to setup-agents
 set-default-shape humans "person"
 set-default-shape dogs "default"

create-humans people [
 setxy random-xcor random-ycor
 set size 1.5 
 set color green
 set sick? false
]

let i 1
while [i <= people] [

  ifelse random 100 < 43 [

    create-dogs 1 [
     set size 0.5
     set color green
     set sick_dog? false
     create-link-from one-of humans [set tie-mode "fixed" tie hide-link]
   ]
  ] []

  set i i + 1  
]

   move

end
```

then , after the link is created I'd need to access an attribute of humasn (has_dog?) and set it to true.

```
humans-own [
  has_dog?
  sick?
]
```

How can I ask to THAT just linked human to set his attribute to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025545/487946) before I saw this one. You'll probably find most of what your looking for over there. That being said:

You probably don't need a `has_dog?` variable, as you can easily figure out if a human has a dog with a reporter:

```
to-report has-dog? ; human reporter
  report any? out-link-neighbors  
end
```

You might still need to access the owner of a dog, though. Here is a reporter for that:

```
to-report my-owner ; dog reporter
  report one-of in-link-neighbors
end
```

(Using links make it theoretically possible for a dog to have multiple owners, hence the `one-of` in the expression. But the way your model is set up, that should never happen. This code would also report `nobody` if a dog had no owner, which makes sense.)

Then, supposing your humans still had a `has_dog?` variable, you could do:

```
ask my-owner [ set has_dog? true ]
```

Some other quick points:

- I notice you have an `ifelse` statement with an empty else clause. Why not just use [`if`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#if)?
- You're using a while loop with a dummy index just to repeat something a number of times. NetLogo has [`repeat`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#repeat) for that.
- The logic of your loop is such that one human could have multiple dogs, because `one-of` could report the same human many times. That's not implausible, but it might not be what you want.
- The previous issue could be avoided by using `ask humans` instead of a while loop, and have the human [`hatch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hatch) a dog with some probability. In general, it's very rare that `while` is the proper solution in NetLogo. You should try to think in terms of agentsets and use things like `while` and indexes as a last resort.

Comment: You've been very kind to me. I hope this hasn't annoyed you. Thanks